# allow non root user to lvm command

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, lvm2

I have to write a script that would allow non root user to display LVM info. I have allowed that user in sudoer file but still not able to run that command returning with following error.

```
  WARNING: Running as a non-root user. Functionality may be unavailable. /run/lock/lvm/P_global:aux: open failed: Permission denied   Unable to obtain global lock.
```

If I run this command from using sudo

```
Sorry, user farooq is not allowed to execute '/sbin/pvdisplay' as root on localhost.
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Edit `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: Please share you /etc/sudoers file

Answer (score -1):

In order to allow a user run a certain script as root you have to edit `/etc/sudoers` or `/etc/sudoers.d/<alt_sudoers_file>`.

You are encouraged to do it using the command `visudo`. If editing alternative sudoers file user `visudo -f <alt_sudoers_file>`.

An example that can work for you would be:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

This actually says the following: Any user of group `sudo`, on ANY host can run ANY command as `root` if the command is prefixed with `sudo`.

For full documentation run `man sudoers`

Answer (score -1):

```
$ lsblk
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                       2:0    1    4K  0 disk
```

Comment: At first glance, this looks like gibberish.  Upon closer look, I see that it appears to be a Unix command, but with no indication of what it means or how it relates to the question.  Please explain it, or it is likely to be deleted. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.